# Array loses data after for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, data-loss

I have the following code:

```
cin >> r >> c;
char map[c][r];
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    string line;
    cin >> line;
    for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
        map[j][i] = line[j];
    }
}


int n;
cin >> n;
//cout << "first " << endl << map[0][0] << endl<< map[1][0] << endl<< map[2][0] << endl<< map[3][0] << endl;

pair<pair<int, int>, pair<int,int>> queries[n];
for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;
    cin >> r1 >> c1 >> r2 >> c2;
    queries[n] = make_pair(make_pair(r1-1, c1-1), make_pair(r2-1, c2-1));
}
cout << "test" << endl;
```

I am experiencing a really weird issue, where my map array seems to lose all its data after the second for-loop. I have breakpoints on the lines "int n;" and "cout << "test << endl;"

On the first breakpoint, my char array is filled with the values i expect, but however on the second breakpoint, all the values in the char array is '\000'.

What could be causing this?

Comment: No idea, but you realise that `char map[c][r];` is not legal C++? In C++ array bounds must be compile time constants. Try using a vector instead. `... queries[n];` is illegal for the same reason.

Comment: You are evidently doing `using namespace std;` but you also use `map` as a variable name. That's "fun things" waiting to happen when `std::map` enters the game. Anyway, if you could turn this into a [mcve] (read: we can throw it into https://godbolt.org, https://wandbox.org/ or similar and it compiles) we can probably help you further.

Comment: Plus there's no check for out of bounds access on `line[j]`, but none of this explains the problem you do see.

Comment: Should that be `queries[k]` instead of `queries[n]`? (I can't really tell what you are trying to do, so I can't say it is wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem one:

```
cin >> r >> c;
char map[c][r];
```

And later:

```
pair<pair<int, int>, pair<int,int>> queries[n];
```

These are variable length arrays (VLAs) which are a feature of C not C++. VLAs are not part of the C++ language, although many compilers support this an extension. Instead, you can use `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` to emulate the behavior.

Problem two:

```
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    string line;
    cin >> line;
    for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
        map[j][i] = line[j];
    }
}
```

This is undefined behavior since the length of the read string can be smaller than c, but the code accesses `c` elements regardless of `line.length()`. It should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    string line;
    cin >> line;
    for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
        map[j][i] = j < line.length() ? line[j] : '\0';
    }
}
```

Problem 3:

Another undefined behavior

```
pair<pair<int, int>, pair<int,int>> queries[n];  // better use std::vector
for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
   ...
   // Out of bounds queries[n]
   queries[n] = make_pair(make_pair(r1-1, c1-1), make_pair(r2-1, c2-1));
```

This last one probably trashes your `map` array. Most likely the out-of-bounds access resides at the same memory location as some of the elements of `map`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.